# How to get IP addresses from Vagrant azure plugin?

Tags: azure, vagrant

I am trying to build a multi-machine vagrant script using vagrant\azure provider. Building the machines under a cloud service is pretty straight forward. However, I am in need to run a bash script to do some provision tasks once the machines are up. In those bash scripts I need to know the IP address (the private IP address of the VM, not the virtual IP).

My understanding (please correct me if I am wrong) is I can't really set private IP to VM instances (even If I define a range in a virtual network, it doesn't guarantee the exact IP ), so I need to know them some how once the machine is created. and before executing the script.

How can I do that? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to request a static IP address for an Azure virtual machine that is being set up in an Azure virtual network using the techniques shown in this Azure documentation: [Set a Reserved Private IP Address for a VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-private-ip/), and in this blog post: [Setting Static IP Addresses in a Virtual Network](http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/setting-static-ip-addresses-in-a-virtual-network/). The solution requires that you are using [Azure PowerShell](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/).

The node.js-based [Azure command line tool](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/) will permit manipulation of a VM's static IP address. Try
`azure vm static-ip --help` for more information.

If the VM is running a UNIX variant, obtaining the internal IP address that a VM was assigned can be done by running the `ifconfig` or `ip` commands and parsing the results as shown in [this unix.stackexchange.com answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87468/is-there-an-easy-way-to-programmatically-extract-ip-address).